# Update menu when switchig between tabs in Android

Tags: android, menu, tabs

I have two tabs in my application and I want the menu to change depending on the Tab.

```
TabHost tabHost = tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo));
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Photos.class);
photospec.setContent(photosIntent);



TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");       
songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.songs));
Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Songs.class);
songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
if (currentTab == 0)
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Photosoptions.class));
if (currentTab == 1)
    {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, Songsoptions.class));
                  } 
        return true;
    }



  @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    int currentTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

    if (currentTab == 0){
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.first, menu);

       }
   if (currentTab ==1){
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);

   }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}



    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            closeOptionsMenu();

        }});
```

Now, when I switch to the songs tab the photos menu is still there until I click on it then the songs menu appears. I want the menu to get updated once I click on the tab

Comment: Provide one snap for better understanding.

Comment: what is value of `tableId` in `onTabChanged`? its equal with current tab or next tab?

Answer (score 0):

you are preparing the option menus in the TabActivity. prepare the option  menus in the individual activity instead. So that when you are on that activity only the option menu for that will be shown.